# Problem with inserting into android sqlite3 table that has composite primary key

Tags: android, sqlite, insert, composite-primary-key

I have a table with a composite primary key and I am having trouble inserting. The code used to create the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE ClassEvent (
    EventName varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
    CourseId varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
    EventType varchar(20), 
    EventWeight number(3), 
    DueDate DATE NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY (CourseId) REFERENCES Courses(CourseId), 
    PRIMARY KEY (CourseId, EventName));
```

The problem I am having is when I want to insert records that have values that may not be unique for the columns CourseId or EventName, but are a unique combination of the 2.
for example, if I try to run the following 2 inserts:

```
INSERT INTO ClassEvent VALUES('Assignment 1','60-415','Assignment',10,'12/10/2010');
INSERT INTO ClassEvent VALUES('Project 1','60-415','Project',15,'5/12/2010');
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: columns CourseId, EventName are not unique.
```

and the second insert does not make it into the DB. Why does this error out? I thought that a composite primary key requires that the **combination** of both values are unique. In my above inserts, the values for the EventName column are different even though the values for CourseId are the same. Shouldn't this be seen as 2 unique combinations and thus 2 different primary keys?

My table needs to be able to hold several different events for each CourseId, but each Event must be unique for each Course. I need to be able to insert values into the table like:

EventName        CourseId
Assignment 1     60-415
Project 1        60-415
Assignment2      60-415
Project 2        60-415
Assignment 1     60-367
Project 1        60-367

and so on. Can anyone tell me how I can get this to work? Why are these composite PK's not being seen as unique entries? Any help would be much appreciated.

---

Here is the java function I am using for the insert:

```
public void addNewClassEvent(ContentValues values) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = openConnection();

    db.insert("ClassEvent", null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

Could this be causing the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a composite primary key in SQLite, but you
have to create the key when you create the table:

```
   CREATE TABLE example1(
      field1 FLOAT,
      field2 TEXT,
      PRIMARY KEY(field1, field2)
   );
```

You cannot create the primary key after the fact using ALTER TABLE.

On the other hand, you can create a UNIQUE INDEX after the fact
which has essentially the same effect as a PRIMARY KEY:

```
   CREATE UNIQUE INDEX pk_index ON "table1"("field1","field2");
```

I am not sure how you have created, the tables, and if you have added the primary index later, but grab the database to your desktop, and check out how works in a desktop environment.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but that is exactly how I created the table. You can view the exact create table script above. Any other ideas?

Comment: Then the data already exists in the table. Do a select with order by on those two fields, and post the section which contains some sample data that fails.

Comment: After running the two inserts above, doing a SELECT * FROM ClassEvent; Returns only the first record. the second insert does not make it into the table.

Comment: I just tried this, and I was able to run both the queries: http://screencast.com/t/5mFXLMbZ and check also this http://screencast.com/t/mfRqHo0XY

Comment: Thanks for all your help, but I still don't know why my table will not allow the insert. Could it be the java function I'm using to do the insert? I'll post it above in the question to see if you have any more insights.

Comment: As I've told you, grab the database and try out in SQLite (there is a plugin for Firefox SQLite Manager you can use that for trying out complex queries too, and working out the best indexes for your faster selects)

Answer (score 0):

You can't make combinations like that, but you don't need them. What is stopping you from just having a truly id column ?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I don't want to use an id column because I don't want entries with the same event name for the same course. For example, I do not want Assignment 1 for 60-415 to be able to be entered twice

Comment: you can have a "assignment 1" + "#" + "event name" as an id. Make sure to have an util function like createId(String assignment, String event) so you don't forget the separator somewhere EDIT: when you get the data, separate it either with lastIndexOf()/a regex or escape the occurrences of the separator character on adding and unescape them on getting (lastIndexOf is easier)

Comment: Perhaps you don't quite understand. Assignment 1 is the EventName and 60-415 is the CourseId. I do not want this combination to be allowed to be entered into the table more than once. However Assignment 1 should be allowed to be entered multiple times as the EventName as long as it's corresponding CourseId creates a unique combination of the two columns. As well, 60-415 should be allowed multiple times as an entry for CourseId as long as it's corresponding EventName creates a unique combination.

Comment: Perhaps you don't understand. This will produce (A,B,C are assignments and 1,2,3 events) : A#1 A#2 A#3 B#1 B#2 B#3 so you can have multiple A-s or multiple 1-s but not twice the same id (not A#1 A#1)

Comment: OK, I guess I didn't understand what you were getting at. You're suggesting I use a utility function prior to the insert to create a unique entry. That should work. Thanks, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: this is the same technique that is used for the Google's Big Table - in GAE (the App Engine), everything is a huge hashmap, and the unique keys are (considering ":" is the separator char) user-id:app-name:table-name:row-id , so when a query for a row D in table C for app B and user A is performed, the search is for A:B:C:D